# Find indexes on two lists based on items condition

Tags: python, list, data-structures, indexing

Lets say I have two lists. They are lists of ratings of books on a scale from -5, to 5.

I want to know when list1's element is `>= 1` and list2's element `== 0`, so for example.

```
list1 = [3, 3, 1, 0, 3, 0, 3, 0, 0, -3, 0, 5, 3, 0, 1, 0, 0, 5, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 3, 0, 1, 0, 0, 3, 5, 3, 3, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 5, 0, 3, 3, 0, -3, 0, 0, 5, 1, 5, 3, 0, 3, 0, 0]
list2 = [5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 1, 0, 5, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 5, 5, 3, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 5, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 5, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

`list1[1] = 3` and `list2[1] = 0`, I want to be able to find all the different indexes of where this happens at.

Sorry if this is confusing but I don't really know how else to word this.

Answer (score 11):

```
>>> [i for i, v in enumerate(list1) if v>=1 and list2[i]==0]
[1, 2, 4, 14, 18, 27, 39, 48, 52]
```

Answer (score 7):

Another variant:

```
>>> [i for i, (l1, l2) in enumerate(zip(list1, list2)) if l1 >= 1 and l2 == 0]
[1, 2, 4, 14, 18, 27, 39, 48, 52]
```

Comment: This is probably what I'd have done. I like the fact that it treats the two list elements similarly (unlike `v` vs `list2[i]`), but treats the index `i` and the elements `l1`,`l2` a little differently, so the syntax fits the semantics.

Answer (score 4):

```
>>>idx_list = [i for i in range(len(list1)) if list1[i] > 1 and list2[i] == 0]
```

Comment: I like this one more because it doesn't create an intermediate variable - the comparisons in the filter are direct (`list1` and `list2` are both there), and easier to mentally track.  No `v` that you have to scan the line for to see how it got defined.

Answer (score 2):

I found this more readable.

```
>>> from itertools import count
>>> [i for i,one,two in zip(count(0), list1, list2) if one >= 1 and two == 0]
[1, 2, 4, 14, 18, 27, 39, 48, 52]
```

And here's the [`itertools.count` doc](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/itertools.html#itertools.count).

Comment: +1 but why have `count(0)` instead of just `count()`? Also i find this to be the best solution.

Comment: @jamylak: Readability. Me too, I'd use this one in my code :)

Comment: Actually looking back on this i think i'd rather do `[i for i,(x,y) in enumerate(izip(list1,list2)) if x>=1 and y==0]` instead of zipping count.

Answer (score 2):

Using NumPy arrays, this is do-able with logical indexing:

```
 import numpy as np
 list1 = np.array([1, -1, 0, 0, 1])
 list2 = np.array([0, 5, 0, 0, 0])

 # Option 1, multiply the logicals together.
 inds = np.where( (list1 >= 1)*(list2 == 0) )[0]

 # Option 2, pure logicals.
 inds = np.where( (list1 >= 1) & (list2 == 0) )[0]
```

Now `inds[0] = 0` and `inds[1] = 4`.

Comment: Probably so, but I always like to think about it as vector arithmetic on an array of booleans. But it's good to make sure folks know that both options exist.

Comment: Come to think of it, `== True` is unnecessary, no?

Comment: Yes, totally. That is an important change. Fixed.